# JS application working with gmail API - client or server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, web-applications, google-api

I'm developing JS application that collects and analyze gmail usage statistics, such as top senders, income/outcome mail per day etc. My first approach was to write thick client and put all API related work on client side. With this approach I don't need servers for backend and can serve this application as static site. But getting deeper I understood it can be easier to write it as backend node.js application. But I don't have enough experience in web development to foresee possible pros/cons of both approaches.

So my question is: what would you suggest me to choose (client or server side) and what important aspect might I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several aspects to consider, amongst which :

1. With server side, you can run tasks when the user is not present, like CRON tasks. Can be useful if your stats generation takes time.
2. Client side looks usually faster to the user : the calls are directly done to the API instead of going to the server fisrt

If you are confident that you will not need to generate statistics when the user is not here, then client side should be fine.